# A good plugin/plugin set for a sports team site?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, theme-recommendation

Looking for a good plugin or group of plugins to handle fixtures, leagues and results.

It needs to handle:

- Fixtures
- Results
- League
- Tables
- Cup routes

Any tips would be gratefully received.----

Comment: I don't personally know of any plugins like this (not to say that there isn't any), but if you find one with just a normal embed code you could always integrate that in. Rather it be through putting it in as a widget or creating a page template.

Comment: Ideally, looking for something built for sports. this is likely to have everything I need.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - Let me suggest you document your list of requirements/ideal features in detail. That will make it a lot more tangible because what one person thinks of as needed for a sports team may be different from what you are looking for. Just a suggestion.

Comment: This seems like a full blown custom web app. Not everything can be solved by WordPress.

Comment: @hakre: I don't agree with the tag you added, `[work-for-free-for-me]`. I don't want to remove it without discussing it, so could you please explain the reason why you added this tag and what it adds to the question?

Comment: @Jan Fabry Can you please tell me what you would like to discuss? It's a tag I used on a question that is open for a longer time, giving requirements that, if answered would most certainly need work to be done for free for the one who asked the question. Naturally this is the case with every question here, I just used it to make the amount of work more prominent for this one.

Comment: I am merely asking if anyone has used a plugin that fit the stipulated criteria. As I have stated in a comment on an answer below, I have the skills to achieve this, the client doesn't have the budget. I won't work for free, I don't expect anyone else to either.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - Thanks for commenting. Is the question still of use to you? It looks like that it won't get answered, so probably it's too specific for the moment?

Comment: an answer would still be of use, probably to the wider community also.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question, well sort of similar. Basically I wanted to create custom post types with the ability to relate one or more post types to other post types. Here is an example as to what I mean. You can decide if you want to go this route or not.

A system that handles employee's for a mega corporation called MegaCorp.

**We have the key required components**:

Projects
Employee's
Tasks

An employee can belong to multiple projects. A project can have multiple tasks, but a task can only belong to one project.

Obviously this it how it could work. Using a plugin like Custom Post Types UI or one of the many others you would create the above components as post types. I prefer the plugin [Easy Post Types](http://www.wpeasyposttypes.com/) but they all do the same thing.

You now want to download this plugin called [Relation Post Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relation-post-types/). There is another and better plugin called Posts 2 Posts by Scribu but unfortunately I couldn't work out how to use it, a bad day perhaps.

Now under settings in the Wordpress admin on the left hand side navigation you should see Relations as a sub-menu item. Set up what post types use what and then go from there.

The only downside to using Relation Post Types is that documentation is very VERY ambiguous, well more like non-existent. But basically to use it you merely calla function which will get the associated post ID's and then you can use get_posts($post_id) to fetch the related post info.

The function is: rpt_get_object_relation(postid, array('posttypeshere')); in one of my current projects I am using it the following way: $related_ids = rpt_get_object_relation($carousel->ID, array('artists')); (inside of a foreach loop) and it seems to get the job done.

I know this goes beyond you asked for, but I believe it can help. You're basically wanting to set up multiple post types and then associate one or more with one another.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
I can suggest 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pods/ 
plugin home: http://podscms.org/ 
But this plugin need some php knowledge to use it for your work.

Comment: It's not a knowledge thing, it's a time thing. Client is paying peanuts, so I am reluctant to code from scratch (which is usually my preferred option.)

Answer (score 0):

I think at the end of the day to ensure forward compatibility and self-sufficiency, you should consider adding **custom post types**. It'd take a little work to weave the taxonomies into it in the form of teams, seasons, etc., but I believe it's all manageable.

Cheers

Noel

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely not use custom post types as suggested by other folks here.

This can and probably should be done completely outside of WordPress. Stats/sports/scores probably work fine in a relational database (tables/rows), so I can see the temptation, but I would just stick it into a new MySQL database and use plugin functionality to interface with WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a way to show the current standings in the league or a list of teammates with info on them you might wanna have a look at "WP Table Reloaded"...

it's a good plugin for creating and showing tables. We use it on our baseball team's website www.poorpigs.de (German)...

Maybe you'd wanna have a look at that...